# Fix/reset default app / "open with"

Tags: music-player, default-applications, dropbox

I have a Samsung Galaxy S21 android phone, android 12.

There has been an issue with playing music from dropbox for many months now.
I can't get my old preferred default music player back.

If I just play a song from dropbox it opens in this player by default:

[image: unwanted default music player]

When I open a song by longpress and choosing "open with" it opens my beloved and preferred music player overlay:

[image: preferred old default music player]

It doesn't show a list of apps to choose from and there are no other music player apps installed on the phone.
There is no option to choose "always".

If I try installing a third-party music player for test, THEN the "open with" shows a list of players including the old preferred default app (white overlay player).
But no matter what I choose and go "open with, ALWAYS", my choice is being ignored onward and it opens this player again:

[image: unwanted default music player]

I have tried doing a reset of app settings on the phone, no change.

I wish to have my old good default music player back ;)

Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "reset of app settings"? Have you looked through Settings -> Apps -> Default apps -> Opening links to attempt to find the undesirable music player and setting it to always ask/clearing it's defaults?

Comment: @l3l_aze I mean I reset/cleared the settings for all apps so it's back to default stock. Don't remember what the exact function was called.
Yes, I have zero music players listed in "default apps"